# let $R$ be a Ring, show that p is a prime element if and only if (p) is a prime ideal in $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

let $R$ be a Ring, show that p is a prime element if and only if (p) is a prime ideal in $R$.

I am puzzled as to what the definition of a prime element would be in a general ring. I thought divisibility is only well defined in integral domains.

Comment: Always mention your question in the body of the post, even if it's repeating the title. Please also skim [this advice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't true in general: $0$ isn't considered a prime element in $\mathbb Z$ (or any ring, for that matter), but it generates a prime ideal.

For a commutative ring and a nonzero element $p$, it *is* true that $(p)$ is a prime ideal iff $p$ is a prime element: one just has to check the definitions.

The choice to use commutativity is just an expediency to stick with the normal definition of "prime ideal" in commutative algebra. Prime ideals of noncommutative rings are slightly more complicated to explain in terms of elements.

> I thought divisibility is only well defined in integral domains.

For a commutative ring, we usually say "$a$ divides $b$ if there exists a $c$ such that $ac=b$."  Where does being a domain come into it?  Asking for it to be a domain buys us other nice things, but it has nothing to do with the definition of divisibility. Divisibility is nothing more than the containment partial-order on the principal ideals, which is always there.

For noncommutative rings one can do something similar but you'd have to take side into consideration. That is not usually something authors take time to do in introductory texts.

Comment: Usually zero is excluded from being a prime element in *any* commutative ring, not just in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I think you meant to write "$(p)$ is a *nonzero* prime ideal iff $p$ is a prime element". Right?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Yes... I don't know how I left that out. I thought I began with "for a nonzero p"

Comment: @DanielHast I have edited for that. I didn't anticipate anyone interpreting it that way. Thanks

Comment: What's the what now with the downvotes?  Not being facetious here, I'm really puzzled.

Comment: You answered the form of question you usually try to close.  Look at the OP's record.  It wouldn't be so much a problem if you didn't spend so much time seeking closure of questions of this quality that you haven't answered.

Comment: That's you choice, I understand, but you seemed "puzzled" by the downvotes. I suggested the obvious. Join the club.  I'm held to a higher standard, too.

Comment: And besides, this user's history goes beyond psq's about "examples/counterexamples".  But I won't tell you what to do.  Just pointing out the obvious.

Comment: @amWhy Sorry, I somehow got comments on different posts mixed up.  My earlier comment about examples does not apply, so I'm deleting to restate.

Comment: @amWhy It's far from obvious. I do not see why this question meets the usual criteria for summary closure.  It's short, yes, but in three sentences (including the title) the user has given an incorrect problem statement and has revealed a misconception. which seems to be context enough to address.

Comment: I will put a stake in the ground here also for anyone else reading: downvoting questions by users who routinely post poor content is defensible, downvoting answers by users who routinely respond to poor content is defensible in some cases, but penalizing the *answerer* because one wants to blackball the *asker* is idiotic.

Comment: Especially in a case like this, it would be up to chance whether or not I would have detected anything warranting reviewing the user's asking history.  Just by evaluating the question at hand, I had no indication that was necessary.  Anyhow it is good to hear that it was probably not because of the content of the answer, and that was my main concern